# Robocraft client not quitting completely after quitting game

Tags: steam, technical-issues, ubuntu, robocraft

Previously, closing the game window would fully quit the application but now it seems that the process remains active in the background, preventing me from relaunching the game (app already running). The app runs indefinitely until manually killed.

```
/home/me/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Robocraft/Robocraft.x86_64
```

I am using 'htop' to locate and kill this process every time that I "close" Robocraft. This has only begun happening in the past two days. It happens whether I close the app using the in-game Quit menu option, or by closing the window itself.

*Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit*

Answer (score 1):

I am also a ubuntu 14.04 x86.64 user, with steam and play robocraft.
this issue has been present since i installed the game which was only about 2 weeks ago.
sometimes when i exit the game steam still says im playing robocraft, i can start another game and steam will still indicate robocraft is the current game.

Upon closing steam, steam complains "Waiting for Robocraft to close.." but then doesnt close essentially leaving the steam running, system shutdown still works though. ;)

What i do is same: 
**Open terminal >  top** 

then 'k' and type the PID# and then enter twice. then 'q'

Sometimes it's difficult to find the process running because it uses very little cpu and mem. Last time I did this, it was using 0.1 CPU and I dont remember the mem.

**Open terminal >  top | grep Robo**
then 'k' and type the PID# and then enter twice. then 'q'